# chrome.scripting.executeScript not working in my manifest v2 Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

```
let save = document.getElementById("save");

save.onclick = function(el) {
    
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id,{code: 'document.getElementById("username").value = "'+login_val+'";' });   
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id,{code: 'alert (document.getElementById("pr_id_5"));' }); 
    
    
        
        })  

}
```

1. send work
2. alert work

.

how to release "get" document.getElementById("pr_id_5") ???

please help.

Comment: `alert` cannot show DOM elements. Use `console.log` and see the output in devtools.

Comment: chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id,{code: 'concole.log(document.getElementById("pr_id_5"));' });

Comment: RESULT :   Uncaught ReferenceError: concole is not defined at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: It's console.log not concole.log.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/184iinZNZKNCSb90GUBY-DQoYIh2MECn1/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: I guess there's another typo in your new code. Show your new code.

Comment: let saveExcel = document.getElementById("saveExcel");

saveExcel.onclick = function() {
 
 chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id,{code: 'console.log(document.getElementById("pr_id_5"));' }); 
 
  });
}

Comment: @wOxxOm console.log work

Comment: how to get : `Excel = (document.getElementById("pr_id_5"));`